# How to loop through filtered values and highlight duplicate cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project that requires me to apply certain filters first, and then once filtered, go through the "company" column of the filtered values. If there is a duplicate, I add the "balance" column for them.

I already figured out the setting of filters initially. Is there a way to loop through the "company" column once filtered, and then perform the addition for duplicate cells? "For" or "For Each" loop? Or are there better options?

Any thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is where I'm currently stuck. I thought of using "For Each" loop but, per my understanding, would need to have access to the company database to check if it matches and then run the summation of balance.

Unsure on how "For" can be applied

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like perhaps a countifs, sumifs, or pivot table situation.

Try a sumifs formula at the end of the table for calculating the balance.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: Hi Brett, could you elaborate on the countifs, sumifs idea? 
I will also try the pivot table solution through VBA since my current running code copies and pastes the filtered value in a temp workbook

Comment: Based on your initial request, you're wanting to identify duplicates and process a balance. That is what a `Sumif` does. For example, `=SUMIF([Company List], [Company Name], [Sum Range])` provides the sums for the column or row for the companies in the list. Transpose the list if the rows should be summed. I used the formula `=IF(COUNTIF($B$4:$B$7, $B4)>1,  SUMIF($B$4:$B$7,$B4,$C4:$C7), 0)`